# How to I split items from a txt file using multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

My txt file looks like this:

```
chihuahua
japanese spaniel
maltese dog, maltese terrier, maltese
```

I'm looking for an

```
output  = ['chihuahua', 'japanese spaniel', 'maltese dog', 'maltese terrier', 'maltese']
```

I'm essentially looking to split the items first by (newline) and then by a comma

I've tried using:

```
dog_n = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('dognames.txt')]
```

and I get the following output:

```
['chihuahua', 'japanese spaniel', 'maltese dog, maltese terrier, maltese']
```

length of list above is 3

I'm looking for a length 5 by splitting all the words

Comment: You could use the `split()` built-in method to split the string based on commas

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace commas with newlines `\n` and use `split` to get a list:

```
dog_n = open('dognames.txt', "r").read().replace(",", "\n").split('\n')
```

Output:

```
['chihuahua', 'japanese spaniel', 'maltese dog', ' maltese terrier', ' maltese']
```

#### Edit:

If you are willing to close file then use:

```
with open('dognames.txt', "r") as f:
    dog_n = f.read().replace(",", "\n").split('\n')
```

Comment: You should add a `close()`